# Unable to create or work on Ubuntu 20.04 VMs after Windows update | ASRock

Tags: 20.04, kernel, virtualbox, windows

After updating windows, I was unable to log in to my Ubuntu VM.

I'm using ASRock Motherboard, which doesn't allow me to setup Linux directly. So I have my ubuntu machine working through Virtual Box.

But after I updated Windows nothing works -

I have tried reinstalling VirtualBox.

Creating a New Ubuntu guest.

Tried Installing Fedora - Failed

Nothing is working.

I get kernel panic, in recovery mode

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=101660

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: Done. Edited...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved -

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/590

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/virtualization-apps-not-work-with-hyper-v

```
dism.exe /online /disable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /norestart
wsl --set-default-version 1
```

Restart Fixed things for me.